# Liferay; Pass other param to jQuery UI aotocompleter

Tags: java, jquery, liferay, jquery-autocomplete

I have a liferay portlet application and I have some jQuery autocompleters. This works fine, but I would like to pass some extra params. I know the names so I created a resourceURL with the params:

```
<portlet:resourceURL id="street" var="jsonStreetResourceUrl">
    <portlet:param name="controller" value="true"/>
    <portlet:param name="term" value="termValue"/>
    <portlet:param name="userTerm" value="userTermValue"/>
</portlet:resourceURL>
```

and my page.tag has some simple autocompleter code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#${comp}\\.targetField").each(function() {
        var that = this;

        $(that).autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                       url : "${controllerURL}",
                       dataType : "json",
                       data : {
                           term : request.term,
                           userTerm: ????????
                       },
                       success : function(data) {
                           response($.map(data.members, function(item) {
                                return {
                                   label: item.name,
                                   value: item.name
                                }
                           }))
                       }
                    })
                   },                     
               });
        });

});
```

Is it possible to pass any userTerm to my controller? When I trying to get the params in contoller I always get userTermValue.

```
    String term = PortletRequestUtils.getStringParameter(request, "term"); // user defined value
    String userTerm= PortletRequestUtils.getStringParameter(request, "userTerm"); // =userTermValue
```

I would like to use something like:

```
userTerm: $("#${comp}\\.infoHolder").val()
```

I read some articles and I found out that I cannot have dynamic number of params but si it possible to have dynamic value of a param?

Answer (score 1):

When generating your URL:

```
<portlet:resourceURL id="street" var="jsonStreetResourceUrl">
    <portlet:param name="controller" value="true"/>
    <portlet:param name="term" value="termValue"/>
    <portlet:param name="userTerm" value="userTermValue"/>
</portlet:resourceURL>
```

What ends up happening to each of the param names is that it is being namespaced. So `userTerm` might end up looking like `_myportlet_WAR_portlet_userTerm`.

I haven't used jQuery in a while...

If the jQuery plugin is supposed to replace the the param in the URL with the one in your data object, you can modify the data object to include the portlet's namespace. Like so:

```
<portlet:namespace />userTerm: ?????????
```

If jQuery does not do this, I would recommend removing the param from your generated URL and namespacing all your params as stated above.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but I cannot do this (EE app) so I will use server sessions and a lot of ajax calling.

Comment: Hi see this link may be useful for you http://liferayway.blogspot.in/2013/08/ajaxjsonliferay-example.html